# Need to copy files with particular extension from multiple folders to a single folder in aws s3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I want all the '*.txt' files from multiple folders copied to one single folder in aws s3 bucket. I used the following command. When the files are copied, it also creates the same folder structure in the target bucket. What am I missing here? Please advice.

```
aws s3 cp s3://source-bucket/ParentFolder/MultipleTxtFilesFolders/ s3://target-bucket/ParentFolder/OneTxtFilesFolder/ --exclude '*' --include '*.txt' --sse AES256 --profile target --recursive
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [cp spec](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/cp.html) does not show an argument called --profile as far as I can tell.

Try

```
aws s3 cp s3://source-bucket/ParentFolder/MultipleTxtFilesFolders/ s3://target-bucket/ParentFolder/OneTxtFilesFolder/ --exclude '*' --include '*.txt' --sse AES256 --recursive
```

If you need to control permissions have a look at --grants

Comment: Profile parameter is required to copy between buckets and managing user access.